# Element div not allowed as child of element ol in this context

Tags: html

I'm trying to validate my code and I'm getting Element div not allowed as child of element ol in this context. What it seems is that I can't have div inside ol, so how can I accomplish what I want without getting this error. I want to be able to have a number list from beginning to end. I don't want the counter top reset. I want to dive the list because I want to be able to toggle between hide and show using jquery. I did search, but I basically found out that it is an error, but could not found other way to do it. 
Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html class="no-js">
                            <head>
                                <meta charset="utf-8">
                                <title>Diff It</title>
                                <meta name="description" content="See the difference between your documents">
                                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
                            </head>
<body>
<!-- first file -->
      <div class="file_wrapper">
        <h2>Previous Version of Pre.report.txt</h2>
        <div class="file_inner">
        <ol class="ol_counter">
<div  style="width: 100%" class="block1"><h3> Result </h3>
<li>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</li>
<li></li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
<li># Test 1. </li>
<li># Test 2. </li>
<li># Test 3. </li>
<li># Test 4. </li>
<li># Test 5. </li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
            </div>
<div  style="width: 100%" class="block2"><h3> Result </h3>
<li>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</li>
<li></li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
<li># Test 1. </li>
<li># Test 2. </li>
<li># Test 3. </li>
<li># Test 4. </li>
<li># Test 5. </li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
            </div>
<div  style="width: 100%" class="block3"><h3> Result </h3>
<li>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</li>
<li></li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
<li># Test 1. </li>
<li># Test 2. </li>
<li># Test 3. </li>
<li># Test 4. </li>
<li># Test 5. </li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
</div>            
</ol>
            </div>                                                                                                      
              </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap the `div` in a `li` otherwise you can't have a div in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply classes to the `<li>` elements by section, then hide them directly instead of hidding the (illegal) containing div:

```
<ol class="ol_counter">
  <li class="section-1">blah</li>
  <li class="section-1">blah</li>
  <li class="section-1">blah</li>

  <li class="section-2">blah</li>
  <li class="section-2">blah</li>
  <li class="section-2">blah</li>
  ...
```

...etc.

Comment: Thanks, what element are allow under ol, because I'm trying to do span and it also giving me an error. Thanks